# Агрегация внутри асинхронной функции множества результатов асинхронных вызовов другой функции

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Предположим есть асинхронная функция `getCollections(callback)`, которая передает в `callback` массив объектов вида `[{ id: 147, name: "My Collection" }, ...]`.

Далее есть еще одна асинхронная функция `getItems(collectionId, callback)`, которая передает в `callback` массив объектов вида `[{ id: 258, name: "My Item" }, ...]`.

Задача в том, чтобы получить все `items` из всех `collections` в одном массиве. Т.е. нужна функция `getAllItems(callback)`.

Наивная реализация:

```
function getAllItems(callback) {
    getCollections(function (collections) {
        var allItems = [];
        var collectionsLength = collections.length;

        for (var c = 0; c < collectionsLength; ++c) {
            getItems(collections[i].id, function (items) {
                Array.prototype.push.apply(allItems, items);
            });
        }

        // Это не сработает т.к. цикл не будет ожидать завершения асинхронных вызовов и завершится.
        // И далее по коду в callback передастся пустой массив allItems.

        callback(allItems);
    });
}
```

Есть ли у данной задачи простое решение на JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов: добавить обертки функциям, которые возвращают Promise

```
function getCollectionsPromise(){
    return new Promise(r => getCollections(r));
}

function getItemsPromise(itemId){
    return new Promise(r => getItems(itemId, r));
}
```

Тогда реализация будет тривиальной:

```
getCollectionsPromise()
    .then(collections => Promise.all(collections.map(collection=> getItemsPromise(collection.id))))
    .then(items => [].concat(...items)) // делаем из [[item,item], [item,item]]  => [item, item, item, item]
    .then(items => console.log(items)) // получаем список всех items
```

Либо с помощью `async`/`await`

```
async function getAllItems(){
    var collections = await getCollectionsPromise();
    var allItems = [].concat(... await Promise.all(collections.map(c=>getItemsPromise(c.id))));
    return allItems;
}
```

---

Но можно и с помощью счетчиков:

```
function getAllItems(callback) {
    getCollections(function (collections) {
        var allItems = [];
        var collectionsLength = collections.length;
        var counter = 0; // считаем сколько коллекций уже обработано
        for (var c = 0; c < collectionsLength; ++c) {
            getItems(collections[i].id, function (items) {
                Array.prototype.push.apply(allItems, items);
                counter += 1; // увеличиваем счетчик обработанных коллекций
                if(counter == collectionsLength) { // если все обработаны
                    callback(allItems); // вызываем callback
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```